# Can two apps have same .xap file name?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xap

I have developed a paid app for `WP7`. Now, I am creating free version by slightly modifying it. Can both the apps have same `.xap` file ? Will it not create any issue for the users who have both the versions ? How to modify the name if required ?

Answer (score 0):

The xap name isn't important, as each app is deployed to a different folder on the phone. Just make sure that both apps have different icons and different names or they'll fail the certification.

Comment: Technically, it's defined in the manifest. But the manifest is re-generated when you submit the app using the information you type in the DevCenter submission form, so you don't have to worry about it until you're ready to submit your app.

Comment: Kindly clarify when manifest is regenerated using typed info, why i need to worry about submission ?

Comment: Well, when you submit the app, don't forget to enter different names and icons for both of them, that's all. The manifest was just the technical aspect, how it works behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

They can have same XAP name or assembly name or namespace, but make sure the ProductID is different when testing and debugging. Otherwise you'll overwrite the first app when deploying but the second app.
By defining two different ProductIDs you are able to deploy them side by side and test them as two different apps.

Comment: product id is auto generated. what is the way to regenerate it or what are the rules to follow while manually changing it

Comment: so product id is only for debugging and not for actual device?

Comment: You're right, the productId is auto generated and after submitting to Store another new one is used. You can use any number there, ideally change just the last number to something new, or generate new random Guid using Tools->Create GUID.

Comment: if store is going to change it , then do i need to change it ?